# Python class, updating

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a bit confused about how to change the name and other attributes in a class. The question says add functions to change the name, change the address.

```
class C:
    
    def __init__(self, name, address):
        self.name = name
        self._address = address
        
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return(f' Name: {self.name}, Address: {self.address})
    
    def update(self, name, address):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        
        return self
```

If I made

```
c = C('Ron', '1111 34st')
Output: Name: Ron, Address: 1111 34st
```

How would I update the name or address?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Minor idiomatic Python note: In general, mutating methods in Python do not return the instance they were called on (they just implicitly return `None`; `list` methods like `append`, `extend` and `sort` are all examples of this). You only return an instance of the class when it makes a new instance (and leaves the original untouched). So `update` should have the line `return self` removed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `update` function implemented in the `Customer` class, you can easily update the name and the address by calling that function on the `c` variable (`c` is called an instance of the `Customer` class):

```py
c = Customer(100, 'Ron', '1111 34st',8881008888 )
c.update('John', '2222 35st')
# Output: ID: 100, Name: John, Address: 2222 35st, Phone: 8881008888
```

You can read more about Python `Classes` and `instances` in:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html